# Adding user input to an objects parameters via a GUI java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm trying to create a program that will take a users input from a JTextField and add that input to an object of the class CurrentAccount after a JButton has been clicked. So far ive been able to come up with this code;

```
jButton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {    
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {


        //Execute when button is pressed
        String currentValue = jTextField1.getText() ;
        int val = Integer.parseInt(currentValue);
        balance = val;
        theAccount = new CurrentAccount(balance);
        System.out.println(theAccount.myBalance);



    }
});
```

but i am receiving errors in the line theAccount = new CurrentAccount(balance). Also i have instantiated theAccount outside of the method as i will need it for an object of the class SavingsAccount as it is of the abstract class Account from which these inherit.

If it helps, my code for the CurrentAccount is as follows;

```
public class CurrentAccount extends Account
{
    private int myBalance;
    private final ControlPanel myPane;


     private int balance;

    public CurrentAccount(ControlPanel myPane)
    {
       // balance= myBalance;
        myBalance = myPane.getDimension();
        this.myPane=myPane;
//        //super(balance);
        //if (100 >= myPane) throw new IllegalArgumentException
        //("A Savings Account can not have a balance of less than £100, you entered" + balance);
    }
```

Any help with this would be really appreciated.

Comment: "i am receiving errors" What errors?

Comment: sorry, should've mentioned. on the line i mentioned im receiving the error "incompatable types: int cannot be converted to ControlPanel" sorry for any confusion

Comment: You've already got an open question on this subject, a question whose comments you've ignored. Please don't re-ask the question, and please don't ignore comments. This question has been closed.

Comment: Im sorry man if you feel that i have ignored your comment but i edited my question to reflect the changes you suggest or at least i felt that i did, my last question did not deal in the code for adding the user input, i merely mentioned it but did not recieve an answer for it, that was my resoning for asking the question in its own question.

Comment: If you've made changes to your code, then please comment back, reply so we know you've made changes, and let us know what happened with the changes. Did you still have the problem? Your previous question did not make sense, in that the code in the method `jButton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {` should not have generated the error that you stated it was generating.

Answer (score 1):

You've got several issues going on with this problem and this code. First and foremost your compilation error message has stated:

> "incompatible types: int cannot be converted to ControlPanel"

This error message was buried in comments and is not part of your main question, making it hard for many to see. Please avoid doing this in the future and instead make it a prominent part of your question.

The error message is telling you exactly what is wrong -- you're trying to create a new CurrentAccount object but are passing an int into its constructor:

```
theAccount = new CurrentAccount(balance);
```

However the constructor has been defined to not accept an int, but rather to accept a ControlPanel object:

```
public CurrentAccount(ControlPanel myPane) {
```

Normally I'd say, that you either need to change the constructor to take an int, or change how you call it so that you only pass in a ControlPanel parameter -- whichever makes most sense. But I don't think **either** is appropriate here. I'm guessing (we can't say for sure just yet because we don't know enough about your overall program structure) that a CurrentAccount instance already exists, and that rather than creating a new one from scratch, you're going to want to pass the balance information into this instance, perhaps with a `setBalance(int balance)` method, if one exists.

For better and more detailed answers, please tell us more about your program's structure and your problem.

Comment: Thanks man and sorry for the repost. I changed the code in the CurrentAccount class to take an integer but that means that i am returning only 0s. I had tried to create a setBalance method but i was unsure as to the structure of the method in the context of using the ControlPanel within the constructor. Also in my MyFrame class where i add the control panel to the JFrame, i managed to get it taking in the user input and adding it to the instance of CurrentAccount the way i wanted it to but this only works via a JMenu and JMenu Items which is less user friendly.